# Ruby - how to slice an array and sum its elements on a condition

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

I can't find a way to achieve the following:

- given an array of Integers
- multiply every second number
- sum all the integers

I tried to use `Enumerble#each_slice` but still no idea on how to call `Array#sum` on a modified array sliced part:

```
input =  [6, 8, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 0]
input.each_slice(2) {|slice| p slice }
#=> 
[6, 8]
[2, 4]
[4, 4]
[5, 5]
[0]
```

Now I'd like to multiply every last element in every pair (a [condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) could be applied before multiplication):

```
[6, 8] => 8 *2
[2, 4] => 4 *2
[4, 4] => 4 *2
[5, 5] => 5 *2
[0]
```

and sum all the numbers of the initial array with its every second number multiplied:

```
[6, 16, 2, 8, 4, 8, 5, 10, 0].sum
```

Any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: what will happen if the last element is not Zero? should it be multiplicated also?

Comment: Nope, only every second element should be multiplied, that's why I tried to use `each_slice(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do exactly that, "multiply every second element and then sum all"

```
input =  [6, 8, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 0]

input.map.with_index{|elem, idx| idx.odd? ? elem * 2 : elem} # => [6, 16, 2, 8, 4, 8, 5, 10, 0]
     .sum # => 59
```

A slight variation of this, not using the index (which *might* placate the reviewer):

```
input.zip([false, true].cycle).
      sum {|elem, is_second| is_second ? elem * 2 : elem}
```

Comment: I've already had this solution using `with_index`and my mentor advised to not use it. Thank you.

Comment: @belgoros: I'd like to hear the reasoning behind that.

Comment: `Using indexing for side effects (I used even/odd or what you used is the same) is a smell.`

Comment: @belgoros: that's weird, because there are no side effects here (or your mentor has "non-standard" definition for this term). Given the problem statement ("multiply every second element"), this code is adequate for the task. Certainly looks better/simpler than jumping through hoops like `each_slice`. IMHO, obviously.

Comment: @belgoros you can find a workaround, but this solution is the correct one. If there's a valid reason to avoid this, you (and we) deserve a clear explanation on why is that, and not an unsourced axiom.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev: may be it's because I didn't describe the task completely saying just that a condition could be applied to the second element in the sliced array. In short, I have to multiply it by 2, then if the result is greater than 9 then subtract 9 from the product. See [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) for more details.

Comment: @Gsk, sure, both solutions worked for me, thank you, guys!

Comment: @belgoros: in this case, this addition to requirements is inconsequential.

Comment: "See Luhn algorithm for more details" - is this from exercism?

Comment: @belgoros: I myself haven't done this exercise for the ruby track. Let's see if it's available to me. :)

Comment: @belgoros here's what I ended up with :) https://exercism.io/tracks/ruby/exercises/luhn/solutions/3b02e9882f68451cb667f29840c8fac0

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option using [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) and [Enumerable#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum), which takes a block:

```
input.each_slice(2).sum { |a, b| a + 2* (b || 0) }
```

Comment: This could be shorter with: `input.each_slice(2).sum { |a, b| a + 2* (b || 0) }`.

Comment: @belgoros, thanks I often forget that `sum` takes a block. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

To throw in another option:

```
input
  .zip([1, 2].cycle)
  .map { |a| a.inject(:*) }
  .sum
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came to is the improved version of @iGian's one:

```
digits = [6, 8, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 0]
digits.each_slice(2).sum { |first, last=0| first + my_custom_function(last) }

def my_custom_function(digit)
  digit *= 2
  digit -= 9 if digit > 9
  digit
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Last 2 lines of method perhaps: `digit %= 9` or just `digit % 9`

Comment: I updated the code, - we could set a default value to `0` for the `last` variable.

Comment: @steenslag: I don't think so.  If the result of this doubling operation is greater than 9 (e.g., 8 × 2 = 16), then add the digits of the result (e.g., 16: 1 + 6 = 7, 18: 1 + 8 = 9) or, alternatively, the same final result can be found by subtracting 9 from that result (e.g., 16: 16 − 9 = 7, 18: 18 − 9 = 9).

Comment: Oh I missed it was luhn exercise. `digit.digits.sum` might be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool = true 
input.map do |e| 
    bool ^= true
    bool ? e * 2 : e
end.sum
```

I like @Sergio Tulentsev answer better and this answer may not use the index but still another variable for side effects.

What I want to know is whether there is a way to give map() a boolean on its way? I've seen something like that in some other language.

Comment: I was going to add this to my answer, but since it was your answer that made me think of this, here, you can have it: `input.zip([false, true].cycle).map {|elem, is_second| is_second ? elem * 2 : elem}.sum`

Comment: Thank you a lot! Please add it to your answer for better visibility though!

Answer (score 0):

just for fun, sticking with each_slice

```
input.each_slice(2).map { |s| s[1] ? [s[0], s[1] * 2] : s[0] }.flatten

# => [6, 16, 2, 8, 4, 8, 5, 10, 0] 

input.each_slice(2).map { |s| s[1] ? [s[0], s[1] * 2] : s[0] }.flatten.sum
# => 59
```